# How to change the title arrow icon in android navigation drawer

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I am new to android. I am trying to use a navigation drawer in my app. That's why I have taken a navigation drawer activity instead of blank activity when created the new project. Now it works fine so far. But I want to change the arrow icon to another image that is at top-left corner at the title bar. I have tried some example on goggle but no result. Can anyone please help me on this please !!! Here are my code below and the arrow image which I want to change >>>

the arrow should change >>>

[image]

My Main Activity >>>

```
    public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity
        implements NavigationDrawerFragment.NavigationDrawerCallbacks {

    private NavigationDrawerFragment mNavigationDrawerFragment;
    private CharSequence mTitle;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mNavigationDrawerFragment = (NavigationDrawerFragment)
                getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.navigation_drawer);
        mTitle = getTitle();

        // Set up the drawer.
        mNavigationDrawerFragment.setUp(
                R.id.navigation_drawer,
                (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout));
    }

    @Override
    public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position) {
        Fragment objFragment = null;
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                objFragment = new FragmentGoogle();
                break;
            case 1:
                objFragment = new FragmentYahoo();
                break;
            case 2:
                objFragment = new FragmentYoutube();
                break;
            case 3:
                objFragment = new FragmentFacebook();
                break;
        }
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.container, objFragment)
                .commit();
    }

    public void onSectionAttached(int number) {
        switch (number) {
            case 0:
                mTitle = "Google";
                break;
            case 1:
                mTitle = "Yahoo";
                break;
            case 2:
                mTitle = "Youtube";
                break;
            case 3:
                mTitle = "Facebook";
                break;
        }
    }

    public void restoreActionBar() {
        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setTitle(mTitle);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        if (!mNavigationDrawerFragment.isDrawerOpen()) {
            // Only show items in the action bar relevant to this screen
            // if the drawer is not showing. Otherwise, let the drawer
            // decide what to show in the action bar.
//            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);     // it's showing the right menu
            restoreActionBar();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}
```

My Navigation Drawer Fragment class >>>

```
    public class NavigationDrawerFragment extends Fragment {

    Boolean isInternetPresent = false;
    ConnectionDetector cd;

    final String[] data ={"Google","Yahoo","Youtube", "Facebook"};
    final String[] fragments ={
            "com.example.user.navigationdrawertoggledemo.FragmentGoogle",
            "com.example.user.navigationdrawertoggledemo.FragmentYahoo",
            "com.example.user.navigationdrawertoggledemo.FragmentYoutube",
            "com.example.user.navigationdrawertoggledemo.FragmentFacebook"};

    private static final String STATE_SELECTED_POSITION = "selected_navigation_drawer_position";

    private static final String PREF_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER = "navigation_drawer_learned";

    private NavigationDrawerCallbacks mCallbacks;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ListView mDrawerListView;
    private View mFragmentContainerView;

    private int mCurrentSelectedPosition = 0;
    private boolean mFromSavedInstanceState;
    private boolean mUserLearnedDrawer;

    public NavigationDrawerFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
        mUserLearnedDrawer = sp.getBoolean(PREF_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER, false);

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            mCurrentSelectedPosition = savedInstanceState.getInt(STATE_SELECTED_POSITION);
            mFromSavedInstanceState = true;
        }
        selectItem(mCurrentSelectedPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        mDrawerListView = (ListView) inflater.inflate(
                R.layout.fragment_navigation_drawer, container, false);
        mDrawerListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager) getActivity()
                        .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
                NetworkInfo networkInfo = connMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();
                if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected()) {
                    selectItem(position);
                } else {
                    showAlertDialog(getActivity(), "No Internet Connection",
                            "You don't have internet connection.", false);
                }
            }
        });

        ObjectDrawerItem[] drawerItem = new ObjectDrawerItem[fragments.length];
        drawerItem[0] = new ObjectDrawerItem(R.drawable.google, "Google");
        drawerItem[1] = new ObjectDrawerItem(R.drawable.yahoo, "Yahoo");
        drawerItem[2] = new ObjectDrawerItem(R.drawable.youtube, "Youtube");
        drawerItem[3] = new ObjectDrawerItem(R.drawable.facebook, "Facebook");

        DrawerItemCustomAdapter adapter = new DrawerItemCustomAdapter
                (getActivity(), R.layout.listview_item_row, drawerItem);
        mDrawerListView.setAdapter(adapter);
        mDrawerListView.setItemChecked(mCurrentSelectedPosition, true);
        return mDrawerListView;
    }

    public boolean isDrawerOpen() {
        return mDrawerLayout != null && mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mFragmentContainerView);
    }

    public void setUp(int fragmentId, DrawerLayout drawerLayout) {
        mFragmentContainerView = getActivity().findViewById(fragmentId);
        mDrawerLayout = drawerLayout;

        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow, GravityCompat.START);

        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                getActivity(),                    /* host Activity */
                mDrawerLayout,                    /* DrawerLayout object */
                R.drawable.ic_drawer,             /* nav drawer image to replace 'Up' caret */
                R.string.navigation_drawer_open,  /* "open drawer" description for accessibility */
                R.string.navigation_drawer_close  /* "close drawer" description for accessibility */
        ) {
            @Override
            public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
                if (!isAdded()) {
                    return;
                }
                getActivity().supportInvalidateOptionsMenu(); // calls onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            }

            @Override
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
                if (!isAdded()) {
                    return;
                }

                if (!mUserLearnedDrawer) {
                    mUserLearnedDrawer = true;
                    SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager
                            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
                    sp.edit().putBoolean(PREF_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER, true).apply();
                }

                getActivity().supportInvalidateOptionsMenu(); // calls onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            }
        };

        if (!mUserLearnedDrawer && !mFromSavedInstanceState) {
            mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(mFragmentContainerView);
        }

        mDrawerLayout.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mDrawerToggle.syncState();
            }
        });

            mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
    }

    private void selectItem(int position) {
        mCurrentSelectedPosition = position;
        if (mDrawerListView != null) {
            mDrawerListView.setItemChecked(position, true);
        }
        if (mDrawerLayout != null) {
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mFragmentContainerView);
        }
        if (mCallbacks != null) {
            mCallbacks.onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(position);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        try {
            mCallbacks = (NavigationDrawerCallbacks) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException("Activity must implement NavigationDrawerCallbacks.");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mCallbacks = null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putInt(STATE_SELECTED_POSITION, mCurrentSelectedPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        if (mDrawerLayout != null && isDrawerOpen()) {
//            inflater.inflate(R.menu.global, menu);        // it's showing the setting icon at right side of action bar
            showGlobalContextActionBar();
        }
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }
        if (item.getItemId() == R.id.action_example) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Example action.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private void showGlobalContextActionBar() {
        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);
        actionBar.setTitle(R.string.app_name);
    }

    private ActionBar getActionBar() {
        return ((ActionBarActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar();
    }

    public static interface NavigationDrawerCallbacks {
        void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position);
    }

    public void showAlertDialog(Context context, String title, String message, Boolean status) {
        AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context).create();
        alertDialog.setTitle(title);
        alertDialog.setMessage(message);
        alertDialog.setIcon((status) ? R.drawable.success : R.drawable.fail);
        alertDialog.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            }
        });
        alertDialog.show();
    }
}
```

My fragment_navigation_drawer.xml >>>

```
<ListView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
android:dividerHeight="0dp"
android:background="#cccc"
tools:context=".NavigationDrawerFragment" />
```

My activity_main.xml >>>

```
    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/navigation_drawer_width"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:name="com.example.user.navigationdrawertoggledemo.NavigationDrawerFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**Edited (Add Manifest)**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.user.navigationdrawertoggledemo" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

</manifest>
```

Comment: Show your Manifest file.

Comment: @ChiragSavsani I have added Manifest. please have a look at it

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14483393/how-do-i-change-the-android-actionbar-title-and-icon try this url.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change the Arrow Icon in the Drawer Menu?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30772629/change-the-arrow-icon-in-the-drawer-menu)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add this Line :

```
 actionBar.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.menuw_24);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the sample code taken from Creating a [Navigation Drawer](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html)

Main Activity

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ... 

    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this,                  /* host Activity */ 
            mDrawerLayout,         /* DrawerLayout object */ 
            R.drawable.ic_drawer,  /* nav drawer icon to replace 'Up' caret */ 
            R.string.drawer_open,  /* "open drawer" description */ 
            R.string.drawer_close  /* "close drawer" description */ 
            ) { 

        /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely closed state. */ 
        public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
            super.onDrawerClosed(view);
            getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
        } 

        /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely open state. */ 
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
            getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
        } 
    }; 

    // Set the drawer toggle as the DrawerListener 
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, but try to give solution on my code cause it would be so helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove:

```
actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

and add:

```
actionBar.setIcon(R.id.ic_...);
```

**Edit:**
By the way read about [Toolbar](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toolbar.html)

Comment: thanks for your reply. But it shows - 'cannot resolve symbol'

Comment: hey I have added this - `actionBar.setIcon(R.drawable.settings);` but still no luck

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for it. Just a single line !! ha ...

add this to your code >>>

```
actionBar.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.settings);  
actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

Note :: // setting is my image name

I hope it will work fine.

Comment: btw my answer is same as your

Comment: ahh my mistake, I did not notice, Sorry, I am accepting your answere.